# Priips : how can we proove that bootstrapping method converges to cornish fisher for category 2 priips products?

Tags: bootstrapping, priips

Bootstraping method used for category 3 products is in fact used also for category 2 products. but how can we mathematically proove that the first one is suitable for category 2 priips and that it converges?

Comment: Please elaborate so that any reader can answer: what are the differences between category 2 and 3 in PRIIPS, and add a link to PRIIPS. A link to Cornish-Fisher would be appreciated too. It will increase your proba to obtain an answer.

Comment: here is a document about the 2 priips categories and the 2 corresponding used methods : https://esas-joint-committee.europa.eu/Publications/Technical%20Standards/Flow%20diagrams%20for%20the%20risk%20and%20reward%20calculations.pdf category 2 product is a product which price is a constant multiple of underlying price like delta one products

Comment: Hi Leyla, the second link you gave was to a file on your harddrive. We can’t access that so I removed it. In general, we expect answers to standalone with minimal reference to outside sources.